# symfony problems at making a form displayed inline

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, symfony-3.3

As the titel already says, I just can't seem to find a way to display my form inline.
This is my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Personeneinträge{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class='container'>
<h1>Personeneinträge</h1>
<form class='form-inline' method="post">
{{ form_start(form)}}
{{ form_widget(form)}}
{{ form_end(form)}}
</form>
```

and this is my Controller:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/homepage", name="homepage")
     */
    public function listAction(Request $request)
    {
        $users = new Users();
        $userssrc = null;
        $name = null;
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $defaultData = array('message' => 'wut');
        $formsearch = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
                 ->add('Suche', TextType::class, array('label'=>'Suche', 'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'style'=>'margin-bottom:0.5cm; width:50%;')))
                 ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'suchen','attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')))
                 ->add('Zurücksetzten', SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'zurücksetzten', 'attr'=>  array('class'=>'btn btn-default')))
                 ->getForm();
         $formsearch->handleRequest($request);
         if($formsearch->isSubmitted() && $formsearch->isValid()){
            $name = $formsearch['Suche']->getData();
            dump($name);
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT u
                 FROM AppBundle:Users u
                 WHERE u.vorname = :name
                 OR u.nachname = :name')->setParameter('name', $name);
            $userssrc = $query->getResult();

            if ($formsearch->get('Zurücksetzten')->isClicked()){
                $textsa = 'Zurücksetzten geklickt';
                dump($textsa);
                return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
            }
            }
        else{
            $vae = 'failed form submission';
            dump($vae);
            }
```

The class .form-inline only displays the label and the textfield on the same line, the buttons are stacked beneath. 
[My rendered page:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSTB1.png)

I've also tried it with CSS and "display: inline" but it made no difference.
I'm grateful for any tips :)
the form looks rendered like this:
[image]

or like this:

[image]

Comment: no one has an idea how to fix this? still having the problem :/

Comment: have the same problem on multiple forms